# Does sendmail need a domain name to function?

Tags: sendmail, php

I have a VPS running WordPress and have tried to install sendmail to enable the php mail() function which WordPress uses. WordPress emails were not being received so I created a test php file containing the mail function to send me a test email.
When run this php file hangs for around 30s before loading with no error messages.
I checked my mail logs and see quite a few of these:

```
Nov 27 22:21:01 sergeserver sm-msp-queue[5866]: unable to qualify my own domain name (sergeserver) -- using short name
Nov 27 22:37:19 sergeserver sendmail[5903]: My unqualified host name (sergeserver) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

Could this be a cause of the mail function not working? As explained in the title my server does not yet have a domain name. I will be pointing my domain to the server this evening but have been developing using the VPS's IP in the meantime.

I have ensured my php.ini contains the sendmail path line

Update:
I have replaced sendmail with postfix as I here it is easier to set up.
I have put the hostname sergedenimes.com in my hosts and hostname files
The mail function is still not working. Here are some of the latest logs:

```
Nov 28 21:20:01 sergedenimes postfix/qmgr[2878]: 1834F2C1EE: from=<smmsp@sergedenimes.com>, size=689, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 28 21:20:02 sergedenimes postfix/local[3171]: 1834F2C1EE: to=<root@sergedenimes.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=1.1, delays=0.03/0.02/0/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Nov 28 21:20:02 sergedenimes postfix/qmgr[2878]: 1834F2C1EE: removed
Nov 28 21:23:06 sergedenimes postfix[3216]: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
Nov 28 21:23:06 sergedenimes postfix[3216]: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
```

Comment: your server does have an ip address, if its connected to the internet.

Comment: I meant domain name. Question ammended

Answer (score 1):

The server's FQDN needs to be fully qualified (hence the name: *Fully Qualified* Domain Name). Even if it is downright false, for testing purposes, set it to something resolvable for the time being in sendmail and on the PHP default domain for sendmail.

And, if your server doesn't have an IP address, you've got a much bigger issue than a sendmail bug - having a server that thinks it's on the internet without being on it! :-)

Comment: Again, it was an error on my part; my server does have an IP address, but not a domain name. Would the lack of domain name be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Configure sendmail to have a FQDN (i.e. something that resolves to something - anything!). It has a significantly smaller probability of hanging once you've done this.

Comment: The reason I my server doesn't have a domain name yet is because the one I'm going to use is live elsewhere. I intend to use sergedenimes.com. Could I use this in the interim for sendmail even though it points to a different server? How would I go about configuring sendmail to have it?

Comment: Yes. A sendmail FQDN doesn't actually impact much (it is effectively used when sendmail relays mails to other servers - read up on the `SMTP` protocol!). The value is set in `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this when I get home as annoyingly my work seems to have blocked whatever port is needed for SFTP so I cannot access my server's files.

Comment: Re: SFTP, When you get home, set up a reverse proxy. You can very easily do so using mod_proxy on apache.

Comment: OK I've got my sendmail.mc file to configure sendmail. Where do I put the FQDN? It is not obvious where anything should go?

Comment: I don't actually have a single box that still runs sendmail (switched to Qmail all around). If you can't find it, go to your hosts file and add sergeserver to map to 127.0.0.1. It does the same thing...in reverse.

Comment: As described above I have replaced sendmail with postfix but it's still not working. sergedenimes.com is in my hosts file

Comment: Your problem is different now - `postfix` came with a different sendmail executable. you'll need to make sure that PHP knows where to find that one.

Comment: I think it is in the same location as the sendmail one: usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: Check just in case. You should be using /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i and piping the message to it.

Comment: `sendmail_path /usr/sbin/postfix -t -i /usr/sbin/postfix -t -i`. Go to your php.ini and change that to what it should be. Also, delete the link to the mark of the cowboy :-)

Comment: That is strange, when I edit my php.ini it has `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` as the page. I shall reboot the server. WHat's the link to the mark of the cowboy?

Comment: Remember, php.ini isn't the be-all-end-all. Depending on server config, you can override some/all properties programmatically. Also, your php.ini is currently set as /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  . That's where you should look first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20270/discussion-between-harryg-and-user1800246)